# AngularJS how ng-route and ng-view single page application different from .load() jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Doing change page without refreshing.

I cannot find different between  routing from angularjs  and .load() jquery?  and is it better than jquery?

Is it about security or something else? 
Thanks

Comment: they both work with ajax so not much difference

Comment: You can have nested states, have resolver between transitionning to a state, you have an angular directive (ui-sref) which allow you to change state without writing javascript... In fact just like everything in Angular compared to Jquery, it is just higher level so much more readable and with a better structure with less efforts. But yes I think too the ajax request seems to be the same.